# Java polymorphism wierd behaviour

Tags: java, polymorphism

Why is the output incorect? 
Do I need abstract class? I've tried that, but it didn't work.
I know c++, but I'm new to java so I understand the concept, but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Output is:
Golf je Mini. Kapacitet: 4 Br kotaca: 6
Golf je Mini. Kapacitet: 4 Br kotaca: 6
Mercedes Nosivost: 3000t  Kapacitet: 4 Br kotaca: 6

Output should be:
Mondeo je karavan. Kapacitet: 5 Br kotaca:4
Golf je Mini. Kapacitet: 3 Br kotaca: 4; 
Mercedes Nosivost: 3000t Kapacitet: 4 Br kotaca: 6

```
public class apples {
   public static void main(String args[]){
   Vozilo Ford = new Auto(4, 5, "Mondeo", "Karavan");
   Vozilo golf = new Auto(4, 3, "Golf", "Mini");
   Vozilo Kam = new Kamion(6, 4, "Mercedes", 3000);
   Vozilo vozila[] = {golf, Ford, Kam};
   Ford.ispis();
   golf.ispis();
   Kam.ispis();
}
}

class Vozilo

    public class Vozilo {
    private static int brKotaca;
    private  static int brPutnika;

    Vozilo(int br, int br2){
        brKotaca = br;
        brPutnika = br2;
    }

    public static void setBrKotaca(int br){
        brKotaca = br;
    }
    public static int getBrKotaca(){
        return brKotaca;
    }

    public static void setBrPutnika(int br2){
        brPutnika = br2;
    }
    public static int getBrPutnika(){
        return brPutnika;
    }

    public void ispis() {
        System.out.println("Vozilo");
    }

}

class Auto

    public class Auto extends Vozilo {
    private static String ime;
    private static String vrsta;

    Auto(int _brKotaca, int _brPutnika, String _ime, String _vrsta )
    {
        super(_brKotaca, _brPutnika);       
        ime=_ime;
        vrsta=_vrsta;
    }
    public static String getIme(){
        return ime;
    }
    public static String getVrsta(){
        return vrsta;
    }

    public void ispis(){
        System.out.println(ime + " je " + vrsta + ". Kapacitet: " + this.getBrPutnika() + " Br kotaca: " + this.getBrKotaca());
    }
    }
class Kamion

    public class Kamion extends Vozilo {
    private static String ime;
    private static int nosivost;

    Kamion(int _brKotaca, int _brPutnika, String _ime, int _nosivost){
        super(_brKotaca, _brPutnika);       
        ime=_ime;
        nosivost = _nosivost;
    }
    public void ispis(){
        System.out.println(ime + " Nosivost: "  + nosivost +"t "  + " Kapacitet: " + this.getBrPutnika() + " Br kotaca: " + this.getBrKotaca());
    }

}
```

Comment: Golf je Mini. Kapacitet: 4 Br kotaca: 6
Golf je Mini. Kapacitet: 4 Br kotaca: 6
Mercedes Nosivost: 3000t  Kapacitet: 4 Br kotaca: 6

This is the output.

Comment: Please edit your question and include it there. What's wrong with that output?

Comment: It should be:
Mondeo je karavan. Kapacitet: 5 Br kotaca:4
Golf je Mini. Kapacitet: 3 Br kotaca: 4;
Mercedes Nosivost: 3000t  Kapacitet: 4 Br kotaca: 6

Comment: I suspect your problem is that brKotaca and brPutnika are static. And, in fact, all of your fields that you are assigning in constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your class variables, getters, and setters as `static`, which means that there is only one of each of those per class, not per instance.

Remove `static` from all your class variables and all your methods, so that each objects gets its own instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

> `private static int brKotaca;
>   private  static int brPutnika;`

By defining these fields as static, you are saying that a single instance of each field should be shared across all instances of the class Vozilo and all its subclasses.  Thus every time brKotaca is assigned a value, that is the value for all instances.  Is this really the behavior you intend?